# Python web scraping data manipulation

Tags: python, string, slice

`Dec 04, 2019200.00200.03198.05198.71198.718,456,300`
For the above string, I am trying to separate it with a `(",")`.
This is the output I'm looking for:

```
(Dec 04, 2019, 200.00, 200.03, 198.05, 198.71, 198.71, 8,456,300)
```

```
stocks = soup.find_all('tr', {'class':'BdT Bdc($seperatorColor) Ta(end) Fz(s) Whs(nw)'})
for i in stocks:
    a = i.text[:12],
    b = i.text[:18],
    c = i.text[:24],
    d = i.text[:30],
    e = i.text[:36],
    f = i.text[:42],
    g = i.text[:51]
    print(a, ', ', b, ', ')
```

I thought I could separate them using index and then inserting commas in 
                              the print function. But it didn't work.

Comment: Please format your code so we can see it better and help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
s = list('Dec 04, 2019200.00200.03198.05198.71198.718,456,300')
for idx in [12, 19, 26, 33, 40, 47]:
    s.insert(idx, ', ')
print(''.join(s))
```

**Output:**

```
Dec 04, 2019, 200.00, 200.03, 198.05, 198.71, 198.71, 8,456,300
```